# IOS run is failing (Application X has not been registered)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm run on IOS is error, but I'm run on android as well

[Screenshort error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU7A5.png)

I'm did linking lin into project.

I do clear cache and reinstall node_modules, but it is not running.

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf yarn.lock && rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn install && yarn start -- --reset-cache`

### I don't find what wrong. Please help me.

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.236
- React Native version: 0.48.4
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): IOS
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Simulator

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.js` file:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MYAPPNAME', () => APP )
```